# Maya to three.js using convert_obj_three.py

Tags: javascript, python, three.js

Lets say I have an `obj` file from Maya2014 like below

***aaaaaa.obj***

```
# This file uses centimeters as units for non-parametric coordinates.

mtllib aaaaaa.mtl
g default
v 7.584940 0.000000 3.298261
v 7.416561 0.000000 2.235156
v 6.927905 0.000000 1.276115
v 6.166806 0.000000 0.515016
v 5.207765 0.000000 0.026360
v 4.144660 0.000000 -0.142020
v 3.081555 0.000000 0.026360
v 2.122514 0.000000 0.515016
v 1.361415 0.000000 1.276115
v 0.872759 0.000000 2.235156
v 0.704380 0.000000 3.298261
v 0.872759 0.000000 4.361366
v 1.361415 0.000000 5.320407
v 2.122514 0.000000 6.081506
v 3.081555 0.000000 6.570162
v 4.144660 0.000000 6.738542
v 5.207766 0.000000 6.570162
v 6.166807 0.000000 6.081507
v 6.927906 0.000000 5.320407
v 7.416562 0.000000 4.361366
v 7.584940 6.330827 3.298261
v 7.416561 6.330827 2.235156
v 6.927905 6.330827 1.276115
v 6.166806 6.330827 0.515016
v 5.207765 6.330827 0.026360
v 4.144660 6.330827 -0.142020
v 3.081555 6.330827 0.026360
v 2.122514 6.330827 0.515016
v 1.361415 6.330827 1.276115
v 0.872759 6.330827 2.235156
v 0.704380 6.330827 3.298261
v 0.872759 6.330827 4.361366
v 1.361415 6.330827 5.320407
v 2.122514 6.330827 6.081506
v 3.081555 6.330827 6.570162
v 4.144660 6.330827 6.738542
v 5.207766 6.330827 6.570162
v 6.166807 6.330827 6.081507
v 6.927906 6.330827 5.320407
v 7.416562 6.330827 4.361366
v 9.484939 6.330827 3.298261
v 9.223568 6.330827 1.648023
v 8.465038 6.330827 0.159323
v 7.283598 6.330827 -1.022117
v 5.794897 6.330827 -1.780647
v 4.144660 6.330827 -2.042019
v 2.494423 6.330827 -1.780647
v 1.005722 6.330827 -1.022116
v -0.175717 6.330827 0.159323
v -0.934248 6.330827 1.648024
v -1.195619 6.330827 3.298261
v -0.934248 6.330827 4.948499
v -0.175717 6.330827 6.437199
v 1.005723 6.330827 7.618638
v 2.494424 6.330827 8.377169
v 4.144661 6.330827 8.638540
v 5.794899 6.330827 8.377169
v 7.283599 6.330827 7.618637
v 8.465038 6.330827 6.437198
v 9.223570 6.330827 4.948497
v 9.484939 0.000000 3.298261
v 9.223568 0.000000 1.648023
v 8.465038 0.000000 0.159323
v 7.283598 0.000000 -1.022117
v 5.794897 0.000000 -1.780647
v 4.144660 0.000000 -2.042019
v 2.494423 0.000000 -1.780647
v 1.005722 0.000000 -1.022116
v -0.175717 0.000000 0.159323
v -0.934248 0.000000 1.648024
v -1.195619 0.000000 3.298261
v -0.934248 0.000000 4.948499
v -0.175717 0.000000 6.437199
v 1.005723 0.000000 7.618638
v 2.494424 0.000000 8.377169
v 4.144661 0.000000 8.638540
v 5.794899 0.000000 8.377169
v 7.283599 0.000000 7.618637
v 8.465038 0.000000 6.437198
v 9.223570 0.000000 4.948497
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 0.500000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vt 0.000000 63308267520.000000
vt 2.000000 0.500000
vn -0.951057 0.000000 0.309017
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000001
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000001
vn -0.951057 0.000000 0.309017
vn -0.809017 0.000000 0.587785
vn -0.809017 0.000000 0.587785
vn -0.587786 0.000000 0.809017
vn -0.587786 0.000000 0.809017
vn -0.309017 0.000000 0.951057
vn -0.309017 0.000000 0.951057
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.309017 0.000000 0.951057
vn 0.309017 0.000000 0.951057
vn 0.587785 0.000000 0.809017
vn 0.587785 0.000000 0.809017
vn 0.809017 0.000000 0.587785
vn 0.809017 0.000000 0.587785
vn 0.951057 0.000000 0.309017
vn 0.951057 0.000000 0.309017
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn 0.951057 0.000000 -0.309017
vn 0.951057 0.000000 -0.309017
vn 0.809017 0.000000 -0.587785
vn 0.809017 0.000000 -0.587785
vn 0.587785 0.000000 -0.809017
vn 0.587785 0.000000 -0.809017
vn 0.309017 0.000000 -0.951056
vn 0.309017 0.000000 -0.951056
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn -0.309017 0.000000 -0.951057
vn -0.309017 0.000000 -0.951057
vn -0.587785 0.000000 -0.809017
vn -0.587785 0.000000 -0.809017
vn -0.809017 0.000000 -0.587785
vn -0.809017 0.000000 -0.587785
vn -0.951057 0.000000 -0.309016
vn -0.951057 0.000000 -0.309016
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.951057 0.000000 -0.309017
vn 1.000000 0.000000 -0.000001
vn 1.000000 0.000000 -0.000001
vn 0.951057 0.000000 -0.309017
vn 0.809017 0.000000 -0.587785
vn 0.809017 0.000000 -0.587785
vn 0.587785 0.000000 -0.809017
vn 0.587785 0.000000 -0.809017
vn 0.309017 0.000000 -0.951057
vn 0.309017 0.000000 -0.951057
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn -0.309017 0.000000 -0.951057
vn -0.309017 0.000000 -0.951057
vn -0.587785 0.000000 -0.809017
vn -0.587785 0.000000 -0.809017
vn -0.809017 0.000000 -0.587785
vn -0.809017 0.000000 -0.587785
vn -0.951057 0.000000 -0.309017
vn -0.951057 0.000000 -0.309017
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn -0.951057 0.000000 0.309017
vn -0.951057 0.000000 0.309017
vn -0.809017 0.000000 0.587785
vn -0.809017 0.000000 0.587785
vn -0.587785 0.000000 0.809017
vn -0.587785 0.000000 0.809017
vn -0.309017 0.000000 0.951057
vn -0.309017 0.000000 0.951057
vn -0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn -0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.309017 0.000000 0.951057
vn 0.309017 0.000000 0.951057
vn 0.587786 0.000000 0.809017
vn 0.587786 0.000000 0.809017
vn 0.809017 0.000000 0.587785
vn 0.809017 0.000000 0.587785
vn 0.951057 0.000000 0.309017
vn 0.951057 0.000000 0.309017
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
s 1
g pPipe1
usemtl initialShadingGroup
f 2/1/1 1/2/2 21/61/3 22/62/4
f 3/5/5 2/1/1 22/62/4 23/63/6
f 4/7/7 3/5/5 23/63/6 24/64/8
f 5/9/9 4/7/7 24/64/8 25/65/10
f 6/11/11 5/9/9 25/65/10 26/66/12
f 7/13/13 6/11/11 26/66/12 27/67/14
f 8/15/15 7/13/13 27/67/14 28/68/16
f 9/17/17 8/15/15 28/68/16 29/69/18
f 10/19/19 9/17/17 29/69/18 30/70/20
f 11/21/21 10/19/19 30/70/20 31/71/22
f 12/23/23 11/21/21 31/71/22 32/72/24
f 13/25/25 12/23/23 32/72/24 33/73/26
f 14/27/27 13/25/25 33/73/26 34/74/28
f 15/29/29 14/27/27 34/74/28 35/75/30
f 16/31/31 15/29/29 35/75/30 36/76/32
f 17/33/33 16/31/31 36/76/32 37/77/34
f 18/35/35 17/33/33 37/77/34 38/78/36
f 19/37/37 18/35/35 38/78/36 39/79/38
f 20/39/39 19/37/37 39/79/38 40/80/40
f 1/2/2 20/39/39 40/80/40 21/61/3
s 2
f 22/4/41 21/3/42 41/81/43 42/83/44
f 23/6/45 22/4/41 42/83/44 43/85/46
f 24/8/47 23/6/45 43/85/46 44/87/48
f 25/10/49 24/8/47 44/87/48 45/89/50
f 26/12/51 25/10/49 45/89/50 46/91/52
f 27/14/53 26/12/51 46/91/52 47/93/54
f 28/16/55 27/14/53 47/93/54 48/95/56
f 29/18/57 28/16/55 48/95/56 49/97/58
f 30/20/59 29/18/57 49/97/58 50/99/60
f 31/22/61 30/20/59 50/99/60 51/101/62
f 32/24/63 31/22/61 51/101/62 52/103/64
f 33/26/65 32/24/63 52/103/64 53/105/66
f 34/28/67 33/26/65 53/105/66 54/107/68
f 35/30/69 34/28/67 54/107/68 55/109/70
f 36/32/71 35/30/69 55/109/70 56/111/72
f 37/34/73 36/32/71 56/111/72 57/113/74
f 38/36/75 37/34/73 57/113/74 58/115/76
f 39/38/77 38/36/75 58/115/76 59/117/78
f 40/40/79 39/38/77 59/117/78 60/119/80
f 21/3/42 40/40/79 60/119/80 41/81/43
s 3
f 42/83/81 41/81/82 61/82/83 62/84/84
f 43/85/85 42/83/81 62/84/84 63/86/86
f 44/87/87 43/85/85 63/86/86 64/88/88
f 45/89/89 44/87/87 64/88/88 65/90/90
f 46/91/91 45/89/89 65/90/90 66/92/92
f 47/93/93 46/91/91 66/92/92 67/94/94
f 48/95/95 47/93/93 67/94/94 68/96/96
f 49/97/97 48/95/95 68/96/96 69/98/98
f 50/99/99 49/97/97 69/98/98 70/100/100
f 51/101/101 50/99/99 70/100/100 71/102/102
f 52/103/103 51/101/101 71/102/102 72/104/104
f 53/105/105 52/103/103 72/104/104 73/106/106
f 54/107/107 53/105/105 73/106/106 74/108/108
f 55/109/109 54/107/107 74/108/108 75/110/110
f 56/111/111 55/109/109 75/110/110 76/112/112
f 57/113/113 56/111/111 76/112/112 77/114/114
f 58/115/115 57/113/113 77/114/114 78/116/116
f 59/117/117 58/115/115 78/116/116 79/118/118
f 60/119/119 59/117/117 79/118/118 80/120/120
f 41/81/82 60/119/119 80/120/120 61/82/83
s 4
f 62/42/121 61/41/122 1/2/123 2/1/124
f 63/43/125 62/42/121 2/1/124 3/5/126
f 64/44/127 63/43/125 3/5/126 4/7/128
f 65/45/129 64/44/127 4/7/128 5/9/130
f 66/46/131 65/45/129 5/9/130 6/11/132
f 67/47/133 66/46/131 6/11/132 7/13/134
f 68/48/135 67/47/133 7/13/134 8/15/136
f 69/49/137 68/48/135 8/15/136 9/17/138
f 70/50/139 69/49/137 9/17/138 10/19/140
f 71/51/141 70/50/139 10/19/140 11/21/142
f 72/52/143 71/51/141 11/21/142 12/23/144
f 73/53/145 72/52/143 12/23/144 13/25/146
f 74/54/147 73/53/145 13/25/146 14/27/148
f 75/55/149 74/54/147 14/27/148 15/29/150
f 76/56/151 75/55/149 15/29/150 16/31/152
f 77/57/153 76/56/151 16/31/152 17/33/154
f 78/58/155 77/57/153 17/33/154 18/35/156
f 79/59/157 78/58/155 18/35/156 19/37/158
f 80/60/159 79/59/157 19/37/158 20/39/160
f 61/41/122 80/60/159 20/39/160 1/2/123
```

***aaaaaa.mtl***

```
newmtl initialShadingGroup
illum 4
Kd 0.50 0.50 0.50
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ni 1.00
```

When I try to convert it using [convert_obj_three.py](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py) I get the error below.
[image]

I have installed Python3.* properly.

What might be the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was giving syntax error so i started checking the syntax. found that it is valid for python 2.*+ not for 3.*+. then i just uninstalled python 3.* it and installed 2.75. not it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have an OBJ file? If not, I suggest using the Maya to THREE exporter that comes with the THREE.js source code. It exports directly to the .JS format without an intermediate step. If you download the repository from GitHub you can find the exporter files in utils/exporters/maya.

The exporter that you would find in the THREE.js official repository only supports static models. I have created an updated version that also supports exporting rigged and animated models. We have a pull request to integrate the updated exporter with the THREE trunk, but if you want to get the new and improved exporter immediately you can get it from this repository: https://github.com/BlackTowerEntertainment/three.js/tree/maya_animation_exporter.

Hope this helps.